# How to code a given jquery into a javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

**I am new to phonegap.So,using JAVASCRIPT for the first time**.I am working in javascript. I am comfortable working with Java Script. I am implementing a plugin for SMS in Phone Gap.

In the tutorial they have asked to use the following code.

```
window.plugins.sms.send($('#phone').val(), 
$('#message').val(), 
function () { 
   alert('Message sent successfully');  
},
function (e) {
    alert('Message Failed:' + e);
}
);
```

Could some one help me out in de-coding the jquery code?

please help me out.

Comment: @ArunPJohny  so you mean to say that this will work under `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> </script>` there is no requirement of external library files for jquery?

Comment: It is a function where you passed the phone number, the text and after  there are the success callback and the error callback.

Comment: All it does it read the values from the elements `#phone` and `#message` and passes it to the `.send()` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementById('phone').value` instead of `$('#phone').val()` to get element's value without jquery.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that function `window.plugins.sms.send` takes a phone number, a message to send, a function to run on success, and a function to run on failure. What that code is doing is providing the first 2 of those 4 things using jQuery selectors, and the last 2 as anonymous functions.

Have a look at http://jquery.com/ (yes, just the homepage) and scroll down to the "A Brief Look" section. That will give you an idea of what the code you provided is doing.

Basically, the tricky bit to get your head around is that `$` in there.

The `$` in jQuery is just the function that instantiates jQuery. Anything in the parentheses immediately after it is a selector, and then everything after that are methods to call on the object returned by the selector.

The code you provided is looking through the DOM for an element called `phone` and an element called `message`. The `#` in front of those means to match only one, unique element. jQuery selectors can also be used to select groups of elements and operate on them all at once.

I'd really recommend going through the jQuery tutorials as they are quite quick to get through. If you already know javascript you'll have little problem getting your head around it.